# How to generate XML from XSD Schema programatically using JAXB?

Tags: java, jaxb

In the below code, i'm generating a xml file from Schema XSD using JLibs library  for this. My question is, how to make something like using library JAXB?

The paramater "file" is a XSD File.

```
   public static boolean makeXmlModel(File file)
  {
      final XSModel xsModel = new XSParser().parse(file.getPath());
   final XSInstance xsInstance = new XSInstance();
    xsInstance.generateOptionalElements = Boolean.TRUE; // null means random
    final QName rootElement = new QName("http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe", "NFe");
    XMLDocument sampleXml;
    try {
        sampleXml = new XMLDocument(new StreamResult("model_xml.xml"), true, 4, null);
          xsInstance.generate(xsModel, rootElement, sampleXml); 
          return true;
         } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
         return false;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there some reason you need to do this from Java code, as opposed to a build script?  Generating code from the JAXB XJC tool from either Ant, Gradle, or Maven is pretty straightforward.

Comment: I'm make a File Mapping XMLs . And the file programmatically transformation is necessary. I would like to turn the XSD file directly to XML without the transformation into classes. Because then I will use this xml.

Comment: I know this is a old question, but those who are in need for a solution, can try this https://santhosh-tekuri.github.io/jlibs/xsd/XSInstance.html . I have used the same to generate millions of random values in the XML files by using XSDs